# Static PAT using Cisco ASA 5506 in cisco packet tracer

Tags: cisco-asa, nat, packet-tracer

```
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/3
ciscoasa(config-if)#nameif inside1
INFO: Security level for "inside1" set to 0 by default.
ciscoasa(config-if)#security-level 100
ciscoasa(config-if)#no shutdown
ciscoasa(config-if)#exit
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/4
ciscoasa(config-if)#nameif outside1
INFO: Security level for "outside1" set to 0 by default.
ciscoasa(config-if)#ip address 172.16.20.1 255.255.255.0
ciscoasa(config-if)#no shutdown
ciscoasa(config-if)#exit
ciscoasa(config)#interface GigabitEthernet 1/3
ciscoasa(config-if)#ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
ciscoasa(config-if)#exitciscoasa(config)# object network outside-mapped-servers
ciscoasa(config-network-object)# host 172.16.20.3
ciscoasa(config)# object network inside-real-ssh
ciscoasa(config-network-object)# host 192.168.10.100
ciscoasa(config-network-object)#nat (inside1,outside1) static outside-mapped-servers service tcp ssh ssh
                                                                  ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker
```

I am trying to implement static PAT using cisco packet tracer and all is fine up to this.can any one tell me what is wrong with this.any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `nat (inside1,outside1) static ?` so we can see what it's expecting in that position?

Comment: Command looks [correct to me](https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/cisco-asa-nat/#staticpat). I'm wondering if Packet tracer doesn't allow using an object as the Static PAT IP address.  Maybe try `nat (inside1,outside1) static 172.16.20.3 service tcp ssh ssh`